# A positive word for self-doubt in a dubious belief system

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a positive word or phrase - though ideally, a single word - that suggests that old dubious beliefs are being re-examined and questioned. "Self-doubt", has a negative connotation and I would like this to indicate a sort of personal growth.

For example, it could describe someone who used to be paranoid and believe that everyone was conspiring against them learning to become more trusting.

Comment: rational, logical??

Comment: @Jim: Those words make sense in context, but don't necessarily stress that becoming more rational was a type of personal growth.

Comment: What is negative about *self-doubt*? How does it conflict with the desire for personal growth?

Comment: How about reflection?

Comment: How about 'realism'?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *self-questioning, self-examination, self-analysis* or *introspection* are somewhere near the target?

Comment: Introspection is very good. I may use that.

Answer (score 1):

The belief is being looked at more **critically** and with **more discrimination** leading to it being applied **less blindly**.

Through being **less blinkered**, they have stopped **seeing everything through the lens** of the belief and have stopped applying it quite so **over-enthusiastically** and are now **more discerning** in its use.

Their **fervour** (**fervor** AmE) has diminished, to be replaced by a more **considered approach**.

Maybe this has come from an increase in personal **humility**?

Answer (score 1):

The term *[awaken](http://www.yourdictionary.com/awaken)* can mean

> To become aware of something: *He finally awakened to the fact that he was wrong*.

[*Webster's New World Dictionary*]